# Structured reading coaching

Tags: pre-schooler, reading

I want to give my child (just about to turn 6) some structure coaching in reading over the summer.

I want to do this myself to see how she's progressing. Are there any sites or books that will provide both a variety of exercises and a structured micro-course on reading that could be done for 30 to 60 minutes a day over the summer? (about 8 weeks)

Comment: In England we use "synthetic phonics". There are a gajillion sources for structured synthetic phonics materials. You probably need to get a cd or dvd or online media to hear the sounds -- it's important to use the correct sounds.

Comment: Stack exchange is an international site! Please, what age is your child? You might want to edit out "kindergarten" and "first grade" (which could be anything between 3 and 7) and edit in the actual age. :-)

Comment: @DanBeale done.

Answer (score 1):

if you haven't tried so, check www.readingeggs.com, the site also offers 2 weeks free trial. I use it for my 6 year old daughter and she loves it.